# how to compare two [][]string arrays in golang

Tags: arrays, string, go

```
func assertEq(test [][]string, ans [][]string) {
    for i := 0; i < len(test); i++ {
        for j := 0; j < len(ans); j++ {
            if test[i][j] != ans[i][j] {
                fmt.Print(test)
                fmt.Print(" ! ")
                fmt.Print(ans)
            }
        }
    }
    fmt.Println()
}
```

In my code it's not checking. I have used two different string arrays to compare each and every character.

Comment: have you tried `reflect.DeepEqual` https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#DeepEqual ?

Comment: Note that `[][]string` is not an array. It's a slice of slices.

Comment: You have already written the code for comparing the slices. What's the problem, exactly (other than missing boundary checks).

Comment: For better performance, check that the slice lengths are equal before checking all the elements are equal. If performance is not a concern you could use DeepEqual as suggested by @AlexEfimov

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking the equality of two slices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15311969/checking-the-equality-of-two-slices)

Answer (score 4):

`i` and `j` are lengths of `test` and `ans`. So, they are not valid index for `test[i][j]` or `ans[i][j]`.

You can simply use [reflect.DeepEqual()](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#DeepEqual).

You can extend [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15312182/4628962) for multiple dimension slices.

One simple example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func assertEq(test [][]string, ans [][]string) bool {
    return reflect.DeepEqual(test, ans)
}

func main() {
    str1 := [][]string{{"1", "2", "3"}, {"1", "2", "3"}, {"1", "2", "3"}}
    str2 := [][]string{{"1", "2", "3"}, {"1", "2", "3"}, {"1", "2", "3"}}
    str3 := [][]string{{"1", "2", "3"}, {"1", "2", "3"}, {"1", "2"}}

    fmt.Println(assertEq(str1, str2)) // answer is true
    fmt.Println(assertEq(str1, str3)) // answer is false
}
```