# Equal vs DeepEqual

Tags: go, reflection, equality

Why is there a difference between Equal and DeepEqual?

```
s1 := "abc"
s2 := "abc"

sv1 := reflect.ValueOf(s1)
sv2 := reflect.ValueOf(s2)

fmt.Println(sv1.Equal(sv2))
fmt.Println(reflect.DeepEqual(sv1, sv2))
```

The first prints true and the second false.

Comment: `reflect.DeepEqual`'s semantics are seldom what you need.

Comment: @jub0bs My expectation was that it just adds recursion for nested data structures.

Comment: That may be the behaviour you _expect_, but is it the behaviour you _desire_? Doubtful.

Comment: @mkopriva How is it possible to access unexported fields?

Comment: @mkopriva Interesting that exporting in Go is just cosmetics.

Comment: @mkopriva But I think it is a design error to make "knowing" the same as "not knowing". DeepEqual must panic or return an error instead of silently returning false.

Comment: @mkopriva It makes a design error not better if you tell everybody that you did it.

Comment: @mkopriva "knowing the answer is false" is definitely not the same as "don't knowing the answer at all". Treating it as the same is just wrong. And this is nothing you can have an opinion about. The only goal for this can be: wanting to be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`reflect.DeepEqual` seems to need some manual unboxing, because it treats `reflect.Value`s just as `struct`s instead of `reflect.Value`s ([example](https://goplay.tools/snippet/ZDR0fvNlB2d)):

```
reflect.DeepEqual(v1.Interface(), v2.Interface())
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you went one meta-level too far.

```
s1 := "abc"
s2 := "abc"

sv1 := reflect.ValueOf(s1)
sv2 := reflect.ValueOf(s2)

fmt.Println(s1 == s2)
fmt.Println(reflect.DeepEqual(s1, s2))

fmt.Println(sv1 == sv2)
fmt.Println(sv1.Equal(sv2))
fmt.Println(reflect.DeepEqual(sv1, sv2))
```

gives:

```
true
true
false
true
false
```

Deep equal adds recurrence, right, and works correctly when examining the concrete types. But the `reflect.Value` objects have different representations.

Do you have any specific reason to query `reflect.Value` objects?

Anyway, hope this helps.

Comment: I stopped using `reflect.Value`.

Comment: But I still do not understand why: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77357582/what-is-the-difference-between-any-and-reflect-value