# What is the difference between any and reflect.Value?

Tags: go

`any` seems to be a dynamically typed value: you can query the type at runtime. The same applies to `reflect.Value`:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func gettype(a any) string {
    switch a.(type) {
    case string:
        return "string"
    case int:
        return "int"
    default:
        panic("todo")
    }
}

func main() {
    var a any
    a = "abc"
    fmt.Printf("%v %v\n", a, gettype(a))
    a = 42
    fmt.Printf("%v %v\n", a, gettype(a))

    var v reflect.Value
    v = reflect.ValueOf("abc")
    fmt.Printf("%v %v\n", v, v.Type())
    v = reflect.ValueOf(42)
    fmt.Printf("%v %v\n", v, v.Type())
}
```

Why does Go need both of them?

Comment: They are totally different. Work through the Tour of Go to learn the basics of Go‘s type system. Note that any is Interface{}.

Comment: @Volker In my example they are exactly the same: a place to store a value with a runtime type.

Comment: in your *contrived* example they look similar. `reflect.Value` has methods and allows you to work with the reflection API, `any` is the empty interface

Comment: A singular example demonstrating that a single operation can be implemented with both, any and reflect.Value proves nothing about reflect.Value and any being equal/isomorph/homeomorph/redundant. There is no simple answer to your question as stated except: Please learn Go's type system. I cannot explain the difference between ω and ω+ω in Set Theory to someone who claims they are the same and one or the other isn't needed, as both allow to count.

Answer (score 2):

Type `any` is an empty `interface`. Note that it's statically typed even though any type satisfies it. So an empty `interface` accepts any value.

But in order to use the value stored in the empty interface you must know which types to expect (like in the type switch in your code). So in practice `any` plays the role of a type union.

The `reflect.Value` on the other hand is used for [reflection](https://go.dev/blog/laws-of-reflection). It allows you to examine the type and the value stored inside an interface variable. This way you can deal with types that are unknown to you. Note that this additional functionality comes with additional overhead.